# Matlab: how to access object values inside an eventhandler?

Tags: matlab, class, events

I am trying to raise an event in Matlab. It is working, but not as i expected. What is going on is that the source object is passed as parameter do the event handler and i can't access my object properties inside the event handler.

Here is my class:

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    properties
        Name = 'a';
    end
    events
        Changed
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass(current)
            if exist('current','var')
                addlistener(current,'Changed',@ChangedHandle);
            end
        end
        function obj = Change(obj,value)
            notify(obj,'Changed');
        end
        function obj = ChangedHandle(obj,value)
            disp(obj.Name);
        end
    end
end
```

These are the command lines to reproduce whats going on:

```
a = MyClass();
b = MyClass(a);
b.Name = 'b';
a.Change(3);
```

This is returning "a" and i want it to return "b".

Regards

Comment: what is significance of the value 3 you are passing into `a` 's `Change` method?

Comment: @BradDay its just an example of class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [listener callback](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/listener-callback-functions.html) you specify receives details of the **object raising the event**. The fact that the listener has been created during the creation of a different object is not an intrinsic property of the listener – unless you effectively embed this in the design of your callback.

In your example, `@ChangedHandle` only works as a callback because it happens to be a method of the class `current` belongs to. If `a` and `b` belonged to different classes the problem would be more obvious: if `ChangedHandle` was a method only of `a`, it wouldn't know anything about the `Name` property of `b`. And if only a method of `b`, the listener bound to `a` would have only the function handle without any reference to the instance `b` of the class to which `ChangeHandle` belongs.

As described in the [listener callback documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/listener-callback-functions.html) you can use a method of the specific object instance `current` as an event listener using the syntax `@current.ChangedHandle`.

This method then receives callback arguments in the format `callbackMethod(obj,src,evnt)`, so you need to add an argument to the definition of `ChangedHandle`. The first argument `obj` will be the instance referenced by `current` when the listener is created, so the line `disp(obj.Name)` will then produce the intended result without modification.

The reference to `a` received by the callback in the example will still be passed to the new callback – this is a fundamental behaviour of listener callbacks – but it will now be accessible from the second argument `src`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `addlistener` code you are not telling the `listener` which object you want to call the method on, so what Matlab does it will apply the listener to the `current` object since thats all that was passed into the function, you can check this by changing the code to:

```
addlistener(current,'Changed',@(h,evt)current.ChangedHandle);
```

if you want it to run the code for the other class `b (obj)`, then you use:

```
addlistener(current,'Changed',@(h,evt)obj.ChangedHandle);
```